# Javascript embed or in a separate file not executed in online server, only in localhost

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a code that show a toast to prevent cookie utilisation. I use cookies to save users that view the message. I've test it in localhost and I't work really good, but I've upload files in my server, and the script not working.

I think that the script isn't loaded. I've tried to embed the code in HTML and create a file `cookie.js` with the code but it's seem to be not execute.

**Edit:** the script work only with my host address (`000webhostapp`) and not with my custom domain name.

Part of my `cookie.js`:

```
function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var elemsTap = document.querySelector('.tap-target');
  var instancesTap = M.TapTarget.init(elemsTap, {});   
  if (!readCookie('tap_target')) {
    if (readCookie('cookie_accept')) {
      instancesTap.open()
      createCookie('tap_target', true, 365,)
    }
  }
  var toastHTML = '<span>Ce site web utilise des cookies, en naviguant sur ce site, vous acceptez automatiquement leur utilisation</span><button class="btn-flat toast-action" onclick=" M.Toast.dismissAll();">OK</button>';
  if (!readCookie('cookie_accept')) {
    M.toast({html: toastHTML , displayLength: Infinity});
    createCookie('cookie_accept', true, 7,)
  }
}
window.onload = codeAddress;
```

In the chrome console, when I write `cookie_accept`, it's said that the variable is not defined.

Comment: After a little while, the script seems to work, it seems to come from browsers.

Comment: It's pretty random

Comment: But `cookie_accept` is not a variable. Write `codeAddress` to see if the function exists. Another thing that could happen is that window.onload is overwritten by another script. Use `window.addEventListener` instead. Actually is highly encouraged to use `addEventListener` instead of `onload` and such. If that's your problem, tell me and I'll write an answer with this so you can accept :P

Comment: Being random I'm pretty sure is going to be the `onload` thing.

Comment: thanks for your response, but the script wotking depending the url. With localhost and my host adress, that working. But with my custom domain name, the script not working.

Comment: https://imgur.com/8TH3wJZ When I write `codeAdress` in the chrome console

Comment: Have you tried the `addEventListener` thing? I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: I have tried, and it's the same thing. I've found the solution, I've disabled cloudfare turbo rocket and now it's work fine ;)

Comment: Kinda weird actually. Glad you found the problem.